# Hypernym for "addition" and "subtraction"

Tags: single-word-requests

For explaining operator precedence in an algorithm, I'd like a hypernym for addition and subtraction.

Comment: Just as in algebra, in computer programming multiplicative operators such as `/`, `*`, and `%` have priority over additive operators such as `+` and `−`, while exponential operators like `**` are even higher in precedence than either of the previous two groups.

Comment: _Operators_ or _operations_ are the usual terms. _Operators_ are metaphorized as agents: _The "times" operator combines `x` and `y` in the following way..._. _Operations_ are events, not agents: _Repeating a number `x` `y` times constitutes an operation of multiplication_.

Comment: Mathematically speaking, multiplication and division are connected but not the same operation, since division requires the use of fractions to be equated to multiplication. Therefore it would be inaccurate to refer to them with one word.

Comment: I edited the question to simplify it because it was clearly hard to understand before. Now please just focus on a hypernym for addition and subtraction. This word should not be a hypernym for division and multiplication though!! The point is to differentiate the operations by precedence.

Comment: @sbwoodside The parallel relations are: Subtraction = addition of additive inverse. Division = multiplication by multiplicative inverse.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm not sure there's a standard term. If I needed to group the operators like this, I would say that addition and subtraction comprise the *additive operators*, and multiplication and division comprise the *multiplicative operators*.

Answer (score -1):

I would label them *final/last operators* since they would be done last and close the question.

Comment: But they might not be the last operations performed.

Comment: I imagine the context might be something like "The <word> operators are done last because they have lowest precedence." Calling them the _last_ operators makes it circular.

Answer (score -1):

Arithmetic is the closest word to what we're looking for. Technically it includes multiplication and division. If you're worried about that, maybe you could emphasize what you're implying by saying basic arithmetic.